# Convert an element in tuple to a bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to base64 encode some RSA encrypted data, but the RSA encryption returns a tuple and the base64 encoding requires a bytes-like object.

> > File "C:\PATH\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\base64.py", line 58, in b64encode encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
>
> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'

I'm looking for suggestions to fix this the best way.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

def rsa_encrypt(data):
    return pub_keyObj.encrypt(data, 32)

def rsa_encrypt_base64(data):
    return base64.standard_b64encode(rsa_encrypt(data))


encrypted_data = aes_encode(data, key, iv) #AES encoding is working fine
print("EncryptedString: ", rsa_encrypt_base64(encrypted_data))
```

Comment: what is the content of that tuple?, can you post an example of data, key and iv?

Comment: The content of the tuple is the rsa encryption and something "empty" like (b'.....e\x89, ' ,) where .... represent a lot at bytes.

Comment: data could be a string or something else I want encrypted. key and IV is generated to make the AES encryption.. and it works fine that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line `return base64.standard_b64encode(rsa_encrypt(data))`, add the index of `0` like this:

```
return base64.standard_b64encode(rsa_encrypt(data)[0])
```

It will fix your problem.

The problem is `rsa_encrypt` will returns a tuple with two items. The first item is the ciphertext of the same type as the plaintext (string or long). The second item is always None.

see [Here](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html#encrypt) for more information.

Comment: wow, such an API... `"The second item is always None"`, now I am curious. Do you know why is it always `None`?

Comment: @Netwave, No I don't, I am curious too. :))